# Does anybody knows how to use Lyx-Latex to create a LNCS document?

Tags: latex, lyx

I already download the extension fro LNCS but I dont know how to use it?
Its my first time using Lyx, Can somebody help me?
I can give my email contact to who can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To create a latex document using the LNCS style, you have to copy the files you downloaded into your main directory. Then using Lyx, you can create a new document based on the article class. To use the LNCS style instead of the article style, edit the source file and replace `\documentclass{article}` by `\documentclass{lncs}`.

You can refer to the Lyx manual to know more about editing a latex document with this application.